# escape all quotes and accents in php variable for javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, escaping, quotes

I have this code:

```
<html>
<?php
$var="\'quotes\" àccènts";  //  'quotes" àccènts
?>
<button onclick="fun('<?php echo $var ?>');">click me</button>
</html>
```

but when I click I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" in the console

I tried this:

```
<button onclick="fun('<?php echo $var ?>');">click me</button>
<?php
function escape($var)
{
    $var=str_replace("'","\\'",$var);
    $var=str_replace("\"","&quot;",$var);
    $var=trim(preg_replace("/\s+/"," ",$var));
    return $var
}
?>
```

but then accents become unknown characters, how can I solve this in inline html?

Comment: https://ideone.com/iEDuy1

Comment: use ajax to return the value you want - mixing JS and PHP is always a bad idea

Comment: please explain why you need inline html for this to work, inlining this in onclick attribute is not possible without corrupting the original string, but maybe a workaround can be found if you explain fully your use case and need for inline html

Answer (score 0):

You can work around it. For example

```
<script>
function fun2()
{
   return fun(<?php echo json_encode($var); ?>);
}
</script>

<button onclick="fun2();">click me</button>
```

In case you want to do this multiple times, for example in a loop in a list of strings,
you can also work around it (unless you want to corrupt the original php strings), by:

```
<script>
// assuming an array of string variables with quotes and accents
var strings = <?php echo json_encode($strings); ?>;
</script>

<?php for($i=0,$l=count($strings); $i<$l; $i++) { ?>
<button onclick="fun(strings[<?php echo $i; ?>]);">Click me!</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I tried but same error: <button onclick="fun(json_encode('<?php echo $var ?>)');">click me</button>

Comment: @Miky, this **is not** what my answer suggested. What you wrote will not work, what I wrote will

Comment: @NikosM.I need an html inline solution

Comment: @Miky why this will not fit you? please explain